# Naming a module 'random.py' leads to numpy attribute errors

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a module called `random.py` which imports numpy and I have been getting a lot of weird attribute errors, like `AttributeError: module ‘numpy’ has no attribute ‘random’`, which I got rid of by renaming the file `randomness.py`  so that it doesn't have the same name like a common package.

Is there some way to work around such errrors, so that I don't have to rename my file?

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do that!" "Then don't do that." Seriously, don't name things the same as Python builtins, you're just inviting trouble.

Comment: "But I like that name, Doctor!" Seriously, I understand that it's not recommended to do that. I am however still asking if there's a workaround.

Comment: Don't be surprised if no answers are forthcoming.  When a problem is so easy to avoid nobody tries heroic efforts at a solution.

Comment: I am perplexed as to how you import numpy, yet numpy.random breaks. But even if you're doing something wrong (I don't know, like, from numpy import *), the fact of the matter is that by keeping your module as `random` prevents you from ever importing the builtin `random` package unless you jump through some hoops. DON'T DO THAT.

Comment: I am actually NOT going to do that for any code that is used in applications that others depend on. I usually find interesting workarounds on this website and I thought I could find something like that in an answer, no heroic effort is expected.

Comment: What I'm saying is that a workaround, if possible, isn't obvious and would require heroic effort to discover.  Nobody will put in that effort when it's so much easier to avoid the problem in the first place.  If you are compelled to discover such a workaround on your own then good luck, but I estimate your odds of success at near zero.

Comment: Change the name of your `random.py` to `my_random.py` perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of smug and salty comments, gee. Here you go, as purely academic exercise - in the vein of code golf if you will. Not something you'd ever really want to use.

Just remove the current directory from `sys.path` while you're importing stuff. This is common knowledge re the python import system.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from copy import deepcopy
import sys
cur_dir = Path(".").resolve()
old_sys_path = deepcopy(sys.path)
sys.path = [x for x in sys.path if Path(x).resolve() != cur_dir]
import random
print(random.__file__)  # Check it's the right random
import numpy as np
sys.path = old_sys_path
```

Comment: This is the kind of heroic effort that I thought was going to be unlikely.  Well done.  It works because once Python imports a module, it's cached and won't be searched for and loaded again so the duplicate file will no longer matter.